# Javascript variable naming convention for compounded words

Tags: javascript, variables, naming-conventions

What would be the correct way to create a variable when it is 'one word' containing multiple words.

For example the word: ice cream

Is there a common convention that says it should be `var IceCream` or `var Icecream`? Since ice cream looks like two words but really is one word.

edit: I know the convention would be CamelCase for multiple words (e.g. black dog would be `blackDog`) but ice cream is really one word with a space in it so `IceCream` does not seem right to me.

Comment: For readability and semantics, CamelCase naming convention is usually recommended. Regardless, this question is primarily opinion-based imo.

Comment: No there is not. Camel case is common but every organization will have their own guidelines.

Comment: *"`IceCream` does not seem right to me."* then do use it. If the code is primarily for you, use whatever you are comfortable with.

Comment: I've always thought of "Ice Cream" as two words that are often used together, not one word, there's nothing wrong with calling it `iceCream`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use camelCase for identifier names (variables and functions). It is a recommended way of using it though it may differ from person to person:

Examples:

```
firstName = "firstName";
lastName = "lastName";

function calculateRect(){
   //...code goes here
}
```